# Where can I get a Font-family to language pair map for Microsoft Word

Tags: ms-word, multilingual, docx4j

I am programmatically generating a MSWord 2011 bilingual file(contains text from 2 languages) using docx4j. My plan is to set the font-family of text based on the language in the text. eg: When I have a Latin and Indian language passed, all text containing English will have 'Times New Roman' and Hindi as 'Devanagari' as their font type.

MS Word documentation doesn't have any information on this. Any help to find a list of all prominent languages MS-Word supports and their corresponding Font-Families appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The starting point is the [rFonts element](http://webapp.docx4java.org/OnlineDemo/ecma376/WordML/rFonts.html).

As it says:

> This element specifies the fonts which shall be used to display the
>   text contents of this run. Within a single run, there may be up to
>   four types of content present which shall each be allowed to use a
>   unique font:
>
> • ASCII
>
> • High ANSI
>
> • Complex Script
>
> • East Asian
>
> The use of each of these fonts shall be determined by the Unicode
>   character values of the run content, unless manually overridden via
>   use of the cs element

For further commentary and the actual algorithm used by docx4j (in its PDF output), which aims to mimic Word, see [RunFontSelector](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/fonts/RunFontSelector.java)

To simplify a bit, you need to work out which of the 4 attributes Word would use for your Hindi (from its Unicode character values), then set that attribute to the font you want.

You can set the attribute to an actual font name, or use a theme reference (see the RunFontSelector code for how that works).

If I were you, I'd create a docx in Word which is set up as you like, then look at its underlying XML. If it uses theme references in the font attributes, you can either use the docx you created as a template for your docx4j work, or you can manually 'resolve' the references and replace them with the actual font names.

If you want to programmatically reproduce what Word has created for you, you can upload your docx to the docx4j webapp to generate suitable code.

Finally, note that the fonts need to be available on the computer opening the docx.  (Unless the fonts are embedded in the docx)  If they aren't, another font may be substituted.